# Mailchimp returns true but email not in list of subscribers

Tags: php, laravel-4, mailchimp

Laravel 4.2

Mailchimp Library: https://github.com/hugofirth/laravel-mailchimp

I have already created a list and added two subscribers in Mailchimp GUI.

```
<?php

$list_id = '******';
$email_address = 'someone@gmail.com';
$subscriber = MailchimpWrapper::lists()->subscribe( 
                 $list_id, array('email'=>$email_address) 
              );    

return Response::json ( [ 
    'response'  => $subscriber
] );

?>
```

Response is true

```
{
  "response": {
    "email": "someone@gmail.com",
    "euid": "d77e6cff13",
    "leid": "50083933"
  }
}
```

But when i check on mailchimp list, I see only 2 emails, the ones that I added via Mailchimp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not super familiar with the laravel library, but typically this happens when you forget to set double-opt-in to false. someone@gmail.com likely got sent a double opt-in confirmation message.

Comment: You got that right! It needs confirmation of the user. How do i disable this? and just one click away its already subscribe?